# Authentication failure on Amazon Linux

Tags: users, login, password, root, authentication

There is an authentication failure when I'm trying to enter password for any of my accounts. I am logged in using ssh to my AWS EC2 instance.

After a while I checked the privileges to files that store user information and found something strange.

I don't think it's normal that:

```
$ ls -l /etc/passwd /etc/shadow
```

Results in this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1402 Oct  7 10:58 /etc/passwd
---------- 1 root root  838 Oct  7 10:58 /etc/shadow
```

This may be the cause of the problem, since no user can read/write the file. In my opinion the normal output for `/etc/shadow` should look something like this.

```
-rw-r----- 1 root root  838 Oct  7 10:58 /etc/shadow
```

Could this be the problem and how can I fix it?

OS config:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2015.09"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2015.09"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2015.09"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2015.09:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2015.09
```

Comment: Here is a related problem: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=533715

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon Linux, a RHEL clone, uses RPM to define the permissions on installed files.  You can use the `rpm -qf /etc/shadow` command to determine the ownership.  This shows that `/etc/shadow` is part of the `setup` package.  You can then use the RPM database to query what the permissions should be for that file.  There's a program called `rpmls` in the rpmdevtools package that does this, but you can do it with simple RPMs if you know the right syntax:

```
$ rpm -q --qf='[%-11{filemodes:perms} %-8{fileusername} %-8{filegroupname} %{filenames}\n]' setup | grep /etc/shadow
----------  root     root     /etc/shadow
```

This shows that it is expected that /etc/shadow are mode 0000.  You shouldn't try to change it to something else.  The PAM stack is perfectly capable of reading the shadow file.  You must have some other problem.

Comment: Thanks. That works, I get the same result. I should then reformulate the question or contact AWS support. My problem seems rather like this: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=533715

Answer (score 0):

Yes you right, the permissions on your `/etc/shadow` seems to be wrong, but this depends on what distribution you are running. Please clarify this point, you can find it out with the following command:

```
# cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.2
DISTRIB_CODENAME=rafaela
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
cat: /etc/upstream-release: Is a directory
```

According to my distro (which is Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela in fact) the default and correct permissions are: -rw-r----- 640 root shadow `/etc/shadow`

you can try to fix them by running following commands with root superpowers:

```
chmod 640 /etc/shadow
chown root:shadow /etc/shadow
```

Comment: It gives me `chmod: changing permissions of ‘/etc/shadow’: Operation not permitted`

Comment: If you have root access to the server, become root and execute commands : ) Otherwise  `chattr -i /etc/shadow` as Nikolay suggested should work, found same solution also here https://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=569413

Comment: My ssh only logs in as user without administrative privileges. I'm running Amazon Linux, but it seems that the problem is not unique to me and affects also other AWS users. I added the output of cat `/etc/*release`.

Answer (score 0):

Like @lese says try :

```
chmod 640 /etc/shadow
chown root:shadow /etc/shadow
```

and if it give's you "Operation not permitted" try :

```
lsattr /etc/shadow
```

and if it says `----i--------e-` then run `chattr -i /etc/shadow` and chmod again.

Comment: The command returns `lsattr: Permission denied While reading flags on /etc/shadow`. Main thing is that I have no privileges at all to the file :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a shadow config issue,

You could try the `shadowconfig on` command

Comment: `shadowconfig` not installed on my system